# All best seller getting as per categorywise. Using Magento Ver 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, best-seller

I did code as per instruction. Make query on `app\code\local\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\bestseller.php`:

```
parent::__construct();
$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
$products = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
    ->addOrderedQty()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'price', 'small_image'))
    ->setStoreId($storeId)
    ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
    ->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc'); // most best sellers on top
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($products);
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($products);
$products->setPageSize(3)->setCurPage(1);
$this->setProductCollection($products);
```

and make phtml code on `app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\product` and make layout code into `catalog.xml` file.

When I try to call all bestseller product then it showing page not found.
I am using URL: `www.xxx.com/catalog/product/bestseller`

Can you please guide me where i wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Vipul Jethva,

In order , **getting product collection of best seller** ,first you ***need to get product ids*** from  **$products** by:

*`$ids =  $products>getColumnValues('product_id');`*

Then **create a product collection** and **filter that collection by `$ids` and category id**

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addIdFilter($ids);
$collection->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => array([CAT_ID])))
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

if($collection->count()):
    // Have best seller
else:
    // no product
endif;
```

In default magento, catalog/product/bestseller does not exit.if you do not use any extension  for this page.

Then you need some customization by create a custom extension:

1. [Override  controller class](http://www.amitbera.com/how-to-override-a-controller-in-magento/) `Mage_Catalog_ProductController`
2. Add new Action **bestseller** at Override controller `[ModuleName]_ModuleName]_ProductController` bcoz you  want to product collection at *catalog/product/bestseller*

Or ,you can manage by cms page by follow [inchoo blog](http://inchoo.net/magento/more-flexible-approach-for-listing-out-products-on-sale-in-magento/)

Comment: I just need to know that how to get bestseller through URL >